# ¿Cómo añadir un identificador de orden en PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, ordenamiento

Tengo una tabla `prueba` en PostgreSQL con una estructura similar a esta:

| nombre | cantidad |
| --- | --- |
| A | 20 |
| A | 30 |
| A | 10 |
| A | 5 |
| B | 8 |
| B | 2 |
| B | 3 |

Necesito añadir una columna que establezca el orden de los registros, basado en el campo `cantidad`, pero para cada grupo de registros con el mismo valor en el campo `nombre`. Es decir, necesito el siguiente resultado:

| nombre | cantidad | orden |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 20 | 3 |
| A | 30 | 4 |
| A | 10 | 2 |
| A | 5 | 1 |
| B | 8 | 3 |
| B | 2 | 1 |
| B | 3 | 2 |

He intentado, sin éxito, lo siguiente:

```
alter table prueba add column orden int;
update prueba 
set orden = t.rownum
    from (select nombre, row_number() over (order by nombre, cantidad) as rownum 
     from prueba) t 
    where t.nombre = prueba.nombre;
```

¿Cómo puede hacerse?

Comment: Te paso la solución en MySQL por si te sirve para traducirla a PostgreSQL: https://dbfiddle.uk/Iq0DvYs0

Comment: Tras un par de intentos con ChatGPT, parece que ha dado con la solución: https://dbfiddle.uk/aNmmu_4a Curiosamente muy parecida a la tuya. No la pongo como respuesta por la política de SO de, por el momento, no usar la IA

Comment: muy interesante lo de `partition by`. No lo conocía

Comment: por cierto, funciona perfectamente, gracias.